# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$status. Laravel 5.5 relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

We are making a laravel project that is for schools. We got a database for schools and inside it are the the users like teachers,staffs ect. My problem is how do I prevent the specific user from a specific school from logging in where their school status is marked = 0 or as inactive in the schools database? I already get the `authenticated` function from vendor but it doesnt work. Is my relationships wrong?

The status is in the `schools` table and not in the `users` table but I already defined the relationships. Look at my models.

User.php

```
public function schools()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School', 'school_id');
    }
```

School.php

```
  public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

LoginController.php

```
  use AuthenticatesUsers;
  public function authenticated(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            //  dd($user->schools());
            if($user->schools()->status == 1){

                dd('active ');

            }
                dd('inactive');
```

Comment: Would it be helpful to create a global scope for status that acted like a kind of soft delete?  As far as the ORM would be concerned, any school with status 0 would not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the property `status` in an object retreived from the eloquent relationship `hasMany` not the relationship itself

```php
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
if($user->schools->status === 1) {
     dd('active');
}
```

Comment: the code `$user->schools->status == 1)`  works sir but if i put `first()->status == 1` it says active even if the user's school is inactive. can you explain it to me sir?

Comment: Make a strict check with triple ===

Comment: Because `belongsTo()` should return 1 object, not a collection

Comment: You're rocking [SO-laravel] tonight :P

Comment: what is the difference between `===` and `==` sir and why i put `first()` even if i put this code works `$user->schools->status == 1` ? i want to know.

Comment: @Vince, try to read your relationships "User belongsTo school", "School hasMany Users" right?

Comment: @Vince I made a mistake because I thought it was a hasMany, remove `first` I updated my answer

Comment: whenever i put `first()` sir it even returns active even if the school of the user is inactive. why is this happening?

Comment: Because it's treating it as a collection when it isn't, remove `first()`

Comment: @Vince - try `dd($user->schools);` and start from there. Also you don't need to do `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` because `$user = Auth::user();` does exact same

Comment: okay sir thank you for your answers. I thought i will create a new middleware about this and im scared because im not into middlewares and im just a newbie haha

Comment: Don't be afraid to fail, post a new question if you get stuck and we're here to help

Comment: @Vince if a User can belong to MANY schools, your relationship should a bit different